# Uploading code to server and run automatically

Tags: python, cloud

I'm fairly competent with Python but I've never 'uploaded code' to a server before and have it run automatically.

I'm working on a project that would require some code to be running 24/7. At certain points of the day, if a criteria is met, a process is started. For example: a database may contain records of what time each user wants to receive a daily newsletter (for some subjective reason) - the code would at the right time of day send the newsletter to the correct person. But of course, all of this is running out on a Cloud server.

Any help would be appreciated - even correcting my entire formulation of the problem! If you know how to do this in any other language - please reply with your solutions!

Thanks!

Comment: please provide more info such operating system, database server type, etc...

Comment: Hey buddy, like I said I'm pretty new to this stuff, so I wouldn't even know which type of server I'd have to upload the code to so that it runs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches to this problem, both of which require shell access to the cloud server.

1. Write the program to handle the scheduling itself. For example, sleep and wake up every few miliseconds to perform the necessary checks. You would then transfer this file to the server using a tool like `scp`, login, and start it in the background using something like `python myscript.py &`.
2. Write the program to do a single run only, and use the scheduling tool `cron` to start it up every minute of the day.

Comment: `nohup` prevents killing the process when closing shell. Also, see supervisord

Answer (score 1):

Took a few days but I finally got a way to work this out. The most practical way to get this working is to use a VPS that runs the script. The confusing part of my code was that each user  would activate the script at a different time for themselves. To do this, say at midnight, the VPS runs the python script (using scheduled tasking or something similar) and runs the script. the script would then pull times from a database and process the code at those times outlined.

Thanks for your time anyways!